# Latest Parity asking to create account everytime

Tags: ether, parity, kovan

I have downloaded the latest version of Parity. Installed it. It started by default and asked to create an account. I created the same and got some ethers from the parity faucet site by requesting manually. Although etherscan site showed that I have 5 ethers but in my parity UI interface it showed 0. Then realized that it default started in Homestead mode. So I closed parity process manually and then started with `parity ui --chain=kovan` parameters.

This time it did open in kovan mode but again it asked to create a new account and there was no way to skip it. I killed parity process. Copied the json key file from `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\ethereum` to `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\kovan` folder again restarted parity with same parameters.

But unfortunately it didn't help and still asked for creating a new account. So need a way to start parity by providing my account details so that it loads the same and doesn't ask to create a new one.

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to use your main network accounts on the Kovan testnet?

Comment: What happens if you go to Accounts -> Create -> Import and just import the JSON keyfile via the UI?

Comment: Initially I created the account in Homestead. Then I started parity in kovan mode. Now after few restarts in kovan mode parity is no more requesting to create a new account rather loading both of my accounts i.e. one created in main network other in kovan. so not sure what was creating that behaviour. Kovan keys are created in C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\kovan

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Kovan testnet's private keys should be stored in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\kovan`?

Start Parity on Kovan chain and create an account as prompted. Verify where the private key is stored and move your private key to that directory.

I suspect Kovan private keys are in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\test` since my Ropsten key is in a directory called `test`, not ropsten. (I am on Mac)

Comment: Ropsten keys are in `test` and Kovan keys in `kovan`, yes.